# start script with arguments sys.argv

Tags: python, arguments, sys

Im trying to start this script with a argument.

When i start the script from a terminal i want to type "python test.py C:\Users\etc\etc\log.log count" to run func1 or error to run func3.

I have try to play around with  `sys.argv / sys.argv[2]` but i cant get it to work.

```
import sys



def func1():
    
    count = 0
    with open(r'C:\Users\etc\etc\log.log') as logfile:
        lines = logfile.readlines()
    for error in lines:
        count += error.count('[error]')  
    print('errors', count)

def func3():

    import re
    
    with open(r'C:\Users\etc\etc\log.log') as logfile:
        for line in map(str.strip, logfile):
            m = re.findall('\[.*?\]', line)
            if len(m) > 1 and m[1] in ('[error]'):
                offset = line.find(m[1]) + len(m[1]) + 1
                print(m[0], line[offset:])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    func1()
    func3()
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting

Comment: @DeepakTripathi Im not getting an error but the scrips run with whatever argument i type. I just want it to run when i type count or error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.argv` is a list containing the arguments passed to the program. The first item is the file name, the rest are the arguments so to get the first argument you use `sys.argv[1]`.
Because the first argument isn't necessarily provided, I've used a try/except block to catch the possible `IndexError`. You can handle this however you like.
You can then just use an if statement to decide which function to run.

```
import sys

def func1():
    
    count = 0
    with open(r'C:\Users\etc\etc\log.log') as logfile:
        lines = logfile.readlines()
    for error in lines:
        count += error.count('[error]')  
    print('errors', count)

def func3():

    import re
    
    with open(r'C:\Users\etc\etc\log.log') as logfile:
        for line in map(str.strip, logfile):
            m = re.findall('\[.*?\]', line)
            if len(m) > 1 and m[1] in ('[error]'):
                offset = line.find(m[1]) + len(m[1]) + 1
                print(m[0], line[offset:])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        arg = sys.argv[1]
    except: pass
    else:
        if arg == "count":
            func1()
        elif arg == "error":
            func3()
```